# How can I find the mistake I am making in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, math

[image]
[image]

In the output, I keep getting -"dollars" and -"cents" instead of positives as shown in the picture.

I have used a class named savings account to set initial balance, deposit and withdraw. And I am asked to use 1 object that prompts the user for input and another that uses overload constructor to initialize dollar and cents.

```
// Include Section
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount
{
public:
    SavingsAccount();
    SavingsAccount(int, int);

    void setInitial(int, int);
    void setDeposit(int, int);
    void setWithdraw(int, int);
    void output();

private:
    int dollars;
    int cents;
};

// Main Function
int main()
{
    // object declaration

    // Bank 1
    SavingsAccount bank1; //has its values set during definition by the user 

    //Bank 2
    SavingsAccount bank2(200, 50); //uses the constructor to store values into member variables
    bank2.setDeposit(40, 50);
    bank2.setWithdraw(100, 98);
    bank2.output();
    cout << "\n\n";

    // Variable declaration
    string repeat;
    int d, c;
    int choice;

    // Prompt for initial balance
    cout << "welcome to your savings account! Please fill in the appropriate information.\n\n";
    cout << "Initial balance (dollars): ";
    cin >> d;
    cout << "Initial balance (cents): ";
    cin >> c;


    bank1.setInitial(d, c);

    do
    {
        cout << "Pick an option: " << endl
            << "1. Deposit money" << endl
            << "2. Withdraw money" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Deposit amount (dollars): ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Deposit amount (cents): ";
            cin >> c;
            bank1.setDeposit(d, c);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Withdraw amount (dollars): ";
            cin >> d;
            cout << "Withdraw amount (cents): ";
            cin >> c;
            bank1.setWithdraw(d, c);
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            while (choice != 1 && choice != 2)
            {
                cout << "Invalid choice,  enter 1 or 2: \n";
                cin >> choice;
            }
        }

        // Display output
        bank1.output();

        // Prompt for continuing
        cout << "\nWould you like to keep going? (y or Y for yes)";
        cin >> repeat;

    }while (repeat == "y" || repeat == "Y");

    cout << "End Program.\n\n";

    return 0;
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount()
{
    dollars = 0;
    cents = 0;
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(int newD, int newC)
{
    dollars = newD;
    cents = newC;
    cout << "Your initial balance is $" << dollars << "." << cents << endl;
}

void SavingsAccount::setInitial(int initialD, int initialC)
{   
    while (initialC >= 100)
    {
        initialC = initialC - 100;
        initialD++;
    }
    dollars = initialD;
    cents = initialC;

    cout << "Your initial balance is $" << dollars << "." << cents << endl;
}

void SavingsAccount::setDeposit(int depD, int depC)
{

    while (depC >= 100)
    {
        depC = depC - 100;
        depD++;
    }
    dollars = depD + dollars;
    cents = depC + cents;

    cout << "Depositing $" << depD << "." << depC << " to your account...\n";
}

void SavingsAccount::setWithdraw(int withD, int withC)
{   
    while (withC >= 100)
    {
        withC = withC - 100;
        withD++;
    }

    if (withD > dollars)
    {
        cout << "Not enough money to be withdrawn.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        dollars = withD - dollars;
        cents = withC - cents;
        cout << "Withdrawing $" << withD << "." << withC << " from your account...\n";
    }

}

void SavingsAccount::output()
{
    cout << "dollars = " << dollars << "  cents = " << cents << endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dollars = withD - dollars` be reversed? current balance (dollars) - withdrawal amount.

Comment: like dollars = dollars - withD?

Comment: @qwerty yes, or simpler: `dollars -= withD;`

Comment: What happens if the account has 100 dollars in it but somebody tries to withdraw 100 dollars and 1 cent?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, still need to add that

Comment: Your making your life very hard by separating dollars and cents, because they're not independent. Why not just one double containing that information?

Answer (score -1):

You ask *How can I find the mistake I am making in my C++ code?* (and not *What is the mistake I am making in my C++ code?*)

Part of the answer to your question is, and this is especially applicable to small programs when you first start learning to program, to trace the execution of your program with pencil and paper.  Then, as your programs become longer and more complicated, start watching their execution with a debugger.

Comment: What about using the debugger on small programs too? It teaches you how to set it up and use it (which in this particular case seems useful). Trying to learn it once it's your last resort can be frustrating (depending on your IDE and environment of course)